# Convert EBNF Grammar to Context-Free Grammar

Tags: java, parsing, context-free-grammar, ebnf

I have to write a JavaCUP specification, and I've been given an EBNF grammar. However, I don't know how to convert between the two. I've heard the basic ideas, but I don't really understand what I need to change, what would be the "terminals", etc.

Can anyone explain how to convert from one to another, or if there's somewhere where I can read about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EBNF grammars are similar to normal BNF, but with some extra features (similar to regular expression operators) as syntax sugar.  Since you did not show your grammar, I can only guess at what parts you need to desugar to convert to normal BNF, but here are the most common (for a LALR generator like JavaCUP):

```
B*    becomes Bstar, defined as Bstar ::= epsilon; Bstar ::= Bstar B
B+    becomes Bplus, defined as Bplus ::= B; Bplus ::= Bplus B
B?    becomes Bquestion, defined as Bquestion ::= epsilon; Bquestion ::= B
B | C becomes BorC, defined as BorC ::= B; BorC ::= C
```

The `epsilon` identifier here is however your parser generator denotes the empty string.

Comment: @Jeremiah: Better. You didn't have to split the other ones; just agree to apply them all until none applies anymore.  But it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Additionally, `{n,m}` can probably be converted as follows: B{3,5} becomes B_x3to5, defined as `B_x3to5 ::= B_x3 | B_x4 | B_x5`, `B_x5 ::= B B_x4`, `B_x4 ::= B B_x3`, ..., `B_x1 ::= B B_x0`, `B_x0 ::= epsilon`. Additionally, whether you add "the rest" on the left or right of these translations will determine whether things are left-associative or right-associative.